# Why enumeration objects can have values other than their enumerators in C?

Tags: c

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{   
    enum C {green = 5, red};
    enum CC {blue, yellow} cc = green;
    printf("%i\n", cc);
    return 0;
}
```

It does compile, and produce console output 5.

[cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/enum) says that "An enumerated type is a distinct type whose value is restricted to one of several explicitly named constants (enumeration constants)". I am really confused.

By the way, the compiler I'm using is gcc version 4.8.1.

Comment: The comment on cppreference is wrong

Comment: @M.M comment updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From std 6.7.2.3 (enumeration content) - the underlying type of `enum` is implementation-defined, but a variable of type `enum` can be assign any number of the underlying type (which is at the very least `char`).

> Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer type, or an
>   unsigned integer type. **The choice of type is implementation-defined, but shall be
>   capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration**. The
>   enumerated type is incomplete until immediately after the } that terminates the list of
>   enumerator declarations, and complete thereafter.

The compiler is NOT required to check that what your store in a `enum` variable is a valid value for that enumeration or not.

Answer (score 4):

You're reading C++ documentation to learn about C? C and C++ are **not** the same language.

In C, an `enum` is effectively an integer type and you're allowed to handle it as such. This means that you can assign an integer to it which may not be one of the prescribed values.

However it's considered bad practice to do so and some compilers or static code checkers have options to warn about such practices.

In C++ on the other hand, enums are distinct types in their own right and you are not allowed to do this in C++, at least not implicitly. Compiling this as C++ results in a compilation error.

Comment: Despite the name, the linked web site contains information for both languages. The linked page contains information for C (not C++).

Comment: The webiste cppreference.com has both c and c++ references. They are completely separated in contents. In C, if an `enum` can have any integer as its value other than one of those declared as its enumerators, it seems that type `enum` is almost identical to integer. From the literal meaning of enumeration, I thought the values of enumeration objects are restricted to an integer set.

Comment: @Carousel I think it is slightly underspecified. But if we take the interpretation that only named members are allowed, then the following would not work:  `enum flags { FLAG_A = 0x01, FLAG_B = 0x02 };` ... `enum flags f = FLAG_A | FLAG_B;`  . However that is a common use of enums and I think the standard committee would have intended that this usage be supported.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, C compiler allow you to do this.

You also can do this:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{   
    enum C {green = 5, red};
    enum C  cc = 7;
    printf("%i\n", cc);

    return 0;
}
```

CPP is really different with C, so don't apply CPP reference to C.

Answer (score 1):

In C there is a contradiction. All enumerations are different types. However their enumerators are integer constants of type `int`.

There is no check whether a given integer value corresponds to the set of specified enumerators in an enumeration.

In C++ the contradiction was eliminated. In C++ each enumerator has the same type as its enumeration where the enumerator is declared and moreover there is no implicit conversion from type `int` to the type of the given enumeration.